# How to turn off autocomplete pop-up, have it autocomplete inline?

Tags: macos, autocomplete, zsh, termius

I don't remember changing autocomplete but recently it started doing a pop-up style that looks sort of like this:

```
                                ┌--------------------------------------------------┐
                                | Press t̲a̲b̲  or c̲l̲i̲c̲k̲ to insert,  e̲n̲t̲e̲r̲ to execute |
                                | clear                                            |
                                | cat /proc/sys/fs                                 |
                                | cfoo                                             |
                                | cbar                                             |
                                └--------------------------------------------------┘
 user@MACBOOK /usr/local/bin % c▯
```

How do I change it back to autocomplete that shows inline with the prompt?

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware that Termius -- the terminal app that I use on my MacBook -- had added an autocomplete function. In the upper right corner, next to the "share session" button was a button labeled "au". I clicked on that button and it had an option to disable autocomplete.

That's what I get for not reading update release notes. In my defense, Termius rolls out new releases too often. In the past six months (at the time I'm writing this) Termius has had twenty-one releases. That's almost a release every week.